# if loop with many parameters ( 1000 && )

Tags: javascript

i have a if loop to check some parameters :

```
if (num1!=0 && A0=="check" && A1!="check" && A2!="check"...)
{}
```

now the problem is A1 go to A1000

the only solution is to write A0=="check" && A1!="check" && A2!="check"....

any smarter solution?

Comment: Why does your function have 1000 arguments? Can you post more of your code, including your for loop?

Comment: why don't you use an array for this? instead of 1000 enumerated variables

Comment: yes array is good idea, but one time i want to check e.g 300 lines and one e.g 400 how to check array position with java script? e.g 1 ... to 300 this time

Comment: `array.slice(0, 300).some(value => value === 'check')` or `array.some((value, index) => index < 300 && value === "check")`

Comment: If you explain what you're trying to achieve with more code people might be able to better advise alternatives as it sounds a bit odd

Answer (score 1):

Generally it looks like a bad practice to have so many enumerated variables.

It would be much better to have `object` or `array` called `A` and put all conditions into this entity.

For example:

```js
var A = [];

A.push('foo');
A.push('ololo');
A.push('check');

// Now if we want to check if there is some value, we can simply do somethink like this

if (A.find(_ => _ === 'check')) {
  console.log ('Some condition is "check"')
}
if (!A.find(_ => _ === 'ururu')) {
  console.log ('There is no "ururu" condition')
}
```

It will also be much better to operate with `array` or `object` in future, when code base and project will grow

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're talking about a for loop for function arguments, or an if statement to check a bunch of variables. So, I have two solutions for you.

## Solution 1 (if statement for a bunch of variables)

```js
var A0 = 'check';
var A1 = 'foo';
var A2 = 'foo';
var A3 = 'foo';
var A4 = 'foo';
var A5 = 'foo';
var A6 = 'foo';
var A7 = 'foo';
var A8 = 'foo';
var A9 = 'foo';
var allCheck = true;

if (A0 === 'check') {
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if(['A' + i] !== 'check') {
      allCheck = false;
      console.log(`A${i} is not check`);
    } 
  }
}

if (allCheck) {
  // Do something here
}
```

## Solution 2 (for loop for function arguments)

```js
function foo (A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9) {
  for (name in arguments) {
    if(arguments[name] === 'check') {
      console.log('dont use check');
    } else {
      console.log('looks good');
    }
  }
}

foo('check', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo');
```

## Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are comparing strings.

```
const assumptions = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const assertions = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let result;

// Using Reduce
result = assumptions.reduce((accumulator, actual, index) => {
  // Remember that false AND something is false
  // Note: here you cannot break the loop, it will run to completion
  return accumulator && actual === assertions[index];
}, true);

// Using Loop
result = true;
for (let i = 0; i < assumptions.length; i++) {
  result = result && (assumptions[i] === assertions[i]);

  // Once it gets to false it will never get to true again
  if (!result) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Note: Assertions could be an array of functions that you call with your assumption as an argument.